# Trying to legalize both versions of my website

Tags: duplicate-content, links, mobile, desktop

I have a desktop version and a mobile version of my website. Since the adoption of the mobile version, my adsense earnings were OK for a short period then dropped all the way down to almost $0 RPM. The only thing I could think of is because I didn't give google enough proof that both sites are related.

If I'm not mistaken, I'm supposed to add to the mobile site:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="desktop.example.com">
```

And I add this to the desktop site:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="mobile.example.com">
```

Is my thinking correct, and is this all I need to eliminate any chance of google believing the two sites are duplicate to each other, or could I add more things as proof?

Comment: Mike- as it turns out I was somewhat wrong. Max provided a link: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/separate-urls?hl=en You do still need to link page to page one at a time, however. But you are right linking mobile to desktop and desktop to mobile. Will edit answer. Sorry for the confusion!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, I was mistaken and @Max steered me in the right direction. Thanks @Max!! Forever grateful! I apologize in advance for the error and confusion.

You **do** want to link your desktop pages to your mobile pages with canonical links. However, you have to link each page to the corresponding page between the desktop and mobile versions.

From mobile:

From desktop:

I still fear that it has nothing to do with your RPM reaching $0 which is a function of clicks on ads served. I suspect there has to be something else fundamentally wrong- and likely something insanely simple to fix. Hopefully, this *is* the answer. I know you have been fighting this battle for a while. I would like to see you find the answer soon. (that is always the way you know... we dance around with big stuff for weeks then it dawns on us what is actually wrong and wha-la! a marvel! too embarrassed to admit or celebrate- but we quietly have a beer anyway. chin-up! you are due for a breakthrough.)

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure I was on the right track. Until now, I never had canonical tags. at one point I was making a few dollars a day, but at the moment I'm making a few cents a day. Hopefully that will change within a few hours.

Comment: My revenue goes up and down as I make mistakes. ;-) I was also making a few dollars most days, less weekends (sorta), I always made a few in the last seconds of Sunday night. People I guess were getting to work half-way around the world. It comes and goes with search trends. I recently changed the SEO profile of my site and while I have the same (paltry) amount of users, the bidding and re-evaluation of my pages in the SERPs has stymied the progress, but it is an effort for higher bid dollars and better ad revenue without sacrificing traffic. When we make changes, we run risks.

Comment: The best hedge against these fluctuations is a cr@p-l0@d of traffic. Something that has so far eluded me. Though I still out perform the market especially as p1$$-p00r as my site really is. That is something to say! I am king of the gutter-dwellers! Whoo-hoo!!

Comment: How is he adding confusion? His explanation of adding the tags is the correct way to make up septate mobile URLs. Just make sure its at a page level, not a site level

Comment: @Max Can you help with a link? My understanding is that a canonical tag/link is to point to the original page. I was careful, but perhaps not clear when I said *If both are the same with the exception of being desktop or mobile*. If my assumption is incorrect, please *absolutely* let me know. I would rather be right for the OP than wrong.

Comment: Sure, here you go:  https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/separate-urls?hl=en, see 'Annotations for desktop and mobile URLs'.

Comment: @Max I did not doubt you! Thanks for the update. I have learned something and updated the answer. Like I said, I would rather be right and learn something new than be wrong and steer someone incorrectly. Thanks again!! I owe you some up-votes! %;-)> (I got a hippie beard and rand paul hair today)